# How to look at each record in RapidMiner Testing Results?

Tags: rapidminer

When a validation is performed, a part of the dataset is used to build a model and then the model is tested on the remaining records in the dataset. I need to look at the result for each record in the testing process, say, for a classification task, I need to know which record is classified as what in the testing phase and what are the records exactly that are used for testing. Can anyone point me to the section in RapidMiner where I can find a table of the tested records and their results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer I posted on the RapidMiner forum - if it's useful perhaps you could acknowledge this?

http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php/topic,7017.0.html

Andrew